# Showing cached server contact and local iOS contact in the same list/tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, contacts

My app uses local iOS contacts together with some server contacts in the same list. 
Server contacts are fetched on startup and saved in `NSManagedObjectContext`. 
Each server contact is represented with Contact class which is subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Local contacts I fetch with `CNContactStore`.

The problem is how to handle this "joining" into single list.

What comes into my mind is:

1.) Save both server and local contacts into same `NSManagedObjectContext` as Contact objects, and fetch it from there. 
-> pros: - fetching is unified 
-> cons: - local contacts are doubled in store memory
         - if user adds new local contact out of our app, it will not be automatically shown in list

2.) Save only server contacts, and every time user goes to contact list fetch local contacts, and append it to list
pros: - contacts are saved only once, local contact updates are always shown 
cons - fetching is not single source, and this complicates things with using `NSFetchResultController`

Maybe there is some other way?

So, what would be best way to show in the same list cached server contacts and local iOS contacts?

Comment: What is `NSContactStore`? If I Google it, this question is the only result.

Comment: No, it's the new iOS9 replacement for iOS Address book

Comment: You mean `CNContactStore` then.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd prefer to keep these two groups of contacts separate rather than combine them in one list. Provide some UI so the user can select their device's contacts database or your app's database, and handle `CNContact` separately from `NSManagedObject`.

If that's not possible (or just not appealing), I'd do something like

1. Save **only** server contacts in my Core Data store.
2. Design my `NSManagedObject` subclass to have a transient property of type `CNMutableContact`. Any time I fetch one of the server contacts, I can get a contacts-style object for it without saving it to the user's contacts database.
3. Fetch all of my server contacts from Core Data, and all of the `CNContact` instances from `CNContactStore`, and merge the results into one array using the property from step 2.
4. Display that array. This would, of course, mean not using `NSFetchedResultsController`, but that's life.

You might want to subclass `CNMutableContact` as well, to add a property that would store the `NSManagedObjectID` of the managed object that created it. Then if the user edits the contact info (if that's allowed) you can use that to find out which managed object you need to change.

Comment: Sorry for late response, thanks, that is what I've ended up doing.